# Centennial app targeting .net higher than installed - What will happen?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I have .net 4.7.1 installed. What if I build a .net application targeting that version of .net, and then package it as a Centennial app - What if someone with an older version of .net tries to install it (from the Windows Store)?

An official link confirming the answer would be nice, if possible.

**EDIT**

Since this seems to be unclear. The Windows Store presumably knows about your computer. The question is just what will it do about it. Will it prompt you to install the newer version like Clickonce can do, or just not let you install the app, or something else?

Comment: if I remember correctly, certification will fail when you submit your app or you will see an error when trying to make an app package.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz how it can fail at that points? OP targets .NET 4.7, packs that as UWP application and distributes. Using .NET 4.7 for that seems valid. Then at later point someone installs application from store but does not have .NET 4.7 installed, only .NET 4.6 for example. What would happen?

Comment: @Evk It may fail in certification process when you submit the app to the Store since their test machine may not have .NET 4.7 installed. I remember I had the wrong version for the first time and something went wrong during the process. I should be the certification that failed.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz then that basically means not all versions greater than 4.6.1 are supported?

Comment: @Evk I'm not sure about that. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/08/28/package-a-net-desktop-application-using-the-desktop-bridge-and-visual-studio-preview/) recommends at least 4.6.1. It also may depend on the minimum target OS build since different versions of .NET are installed on different builds.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz As far as I know there is no upper limit on the .net version possible for certification. The question is only about the target machine.

Comment: @ispiro Your app will be tested on a machine to pass the certification. If the target machine does not have that version of .NET installed, your app won't pass the certification. Not all the Windows 10 versions have the most new .NET installed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Keep in mind that Centennial is a bridge.

Centennial apps run on Windows 10 Anniversary edition (10.0; Build 14393) or later. On this Windows version the default installed .NET version is [4.6.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/). Windows 10 Creators Update comes with .NET 4.7 by default.

So, if someone downloads your application on Windows 10 Anniversary edition and tries to run it, the following can happen:

- .NET 4.6.2 is installed, your application doesn't use anything from .NET 4.7.1: your application works properly
- .NET 4.6.2 is installed, your application is using .NET 4.7.1 [specific features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/): your application doesn't work properly
- .NET 4.7.1 is installed, your application doesn't use anything form .NET 4.7.1: your application works properly
- .NET 4.7.1 is installed, your application is using .NET 4.7.1 specific features: your application works properly

You can apply the same logic for the later versions of Windows 10.

Another interesting option would be to package .NET 4.7.1 along with your application. If I understand it [correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes), the Centennial apps have a virtual file system, which is basically merged with the real one. So, you should be able to install .NET 4.7.1 with your application and then package it together with your application. Then it will work on Windows 10 Anniversary edition as well on the later editions.

Comment: How do you know that Windows won't download the newer version of .net (perhaps asking the user first)?

Comment: Why would it? How would it know?

Comment: The Windows Store app, which is how you download it, will know. Just like Clickonce. There is no question of whether it will know. Just what will it do.

Comment: I can hardly imagine that it would download a newer version of .NET. ClickOnce is completely different, in a Centennial app I can do anything, even use a completely different framework. If you don't specify your need to use a specific framework in a configuration or somewhere, then Centennial would not know about it. That's my point...